# Sort and find Top and Bottom 5 values and their corresponding names

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I know this is not the first time someone is asking a similar question, but me trying to execute what I found out in other answers is not working exactly as how I want it to be. I hope someone here could help me.

I got four columns, the first one is the Product Name, and the last one is its P/L%. I want to sort out top and bottom 5 P/L% value along with their corresponding Product Name. I am attaching the screenshot of a sample scenario in case if you couldn't understand what I explained.

[image: Sample Spreadsheet Screenshot]

I tried the (sort(filter)) method as found somewhere else, but it actually messed up with the second and third columns. I hope someone here can give me some simple ways.

Comment: What version of Excel? Show what you tried and how it "messed up". I don't see why you would need the 2nd or 3rd columns in the results.  Also, how do you want to handle duplicate P/L%'s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution considers the case when multiple products has same value in P/L% and I use a Table object for displayed data.

## Formulas to use

---

### Top 5 Gainers values

**=LARGE(ProductTable[P/L%]; ROWS($H$3:H3))**, and copy down

[Top 5 Gainer values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXwJ5.png)

### Top 5 Gainers products name

**=INDEX(ProductTable[Product Name];AGGREGATE(14;6;(ROW(ProductTable[P/L%])-ROW(D$2)+1)/(ProductTable[P/L%]=H3);COUNTIF($H$3:H3;H3)))**, and copy down

[Top 5 Gainers products name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wufkA.png)

### Top 5 Loosers values

**=SMALL(ProductTable[P/L%];ROWS($H$3:H3))**, and copy down

[Top 5 Loosers values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yg3l.png)

### Top 5 Loosers products name

**=INDEX(ProductTable[Product Name];AGGREGATE(14;6;(ROW(ProductTable[P/L%])-ROW(D$2)+1)/(ProductTable[P/L%]=K3);COUNTIF($K$3:K3;K3)))**, and copy down

[Top 5 Loosers products name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGu2P.png)

## Short Explanation

You must use **LARGE** and **SMALL** functions when you want to get the largest or the smallest value in a data array.

**AGGREGATE** function is a little bit complex to explain here so I recommend you [this link](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-aggregate-function) to understand better. Basically, I use this formula to get the row of the *gainer* or *looser* product name into **INDEX** function.

**ROWS($H$3:H3)** returns 1, but when you copy down this formula, you get 2, 3, and so on. This is a nice way to expand the query if you need more than top 5 values.

---

Similar problem in:
https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1208726-index-match-large-and-duplicates.html